# how to  solve the duplicate symbol error in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created an application .but when i run my application i get 2 errors.i dont understand the errors.
1st error is

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/mapc failed with exit code 6
```

and the other error is of duplicate symbol 
i.e

```
ld: warning: duplicate dylib /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/system/libSystem.host.dylib   

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_PostPreviewViewController.webView in /Users/rajinair/Desktop/trunk/build/WordPress.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WordPress.build/Objects-normal/i386/PostPreviewViewController-27138F5DB4996E35.o and /Users/rajinair/Desktop/trunk/build/WordPress.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WordPress.build/Objects-normal/i386/PostPreviewViewController-27138F5DB4996E35.o

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

what may be the problem. I dont understand the problem. Please help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PostPreviewViewController.webView` is defined multiple times. Post code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have recursive import, such as **FileA.h** contains `#import "FileB.h"` and **FileB.h** contains `#import FileA.h`. You should keep most of your imports in the .m file.